# Write a program to receive input from user and check its spelling

Tags: java

I have written code to find if two strings are equal or not.  The first string input should be given by the user and it should be compared with a second string which is predefined.  But even when I am giving an input that is the same as the second string, the output is incorrect.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class correction {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i,c=0;
        String[] s1=new String[] {"F","R","I","E","N","D","S"};
        String[] s2=new String[7];
        System.out.println("enter a alphabet");
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        s2[0]=sc.next();
        s2[1]=sc.next();
        s2[2]=sc.next();
        s2[3]=sc.next();
        s2[4]=sc.next();
        s2[5]=sc.next();
        s2[6]=sc.next();
        int length = s1.length;
        for(i=0;i<length;i++)
        {
        if(s1.equals(s2[i]))
        c++;    
        }
        if(c==7)
            System.out.println("right way");    
        else
            System.out.println("wrong way");
    }
}
```

I expected the output to be "right way" but the output is "wrong way".  And c value is also 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently comparing the entire array `s1` with a specific letter in `s2` in each iteration of your for loop. What you should be doing instead is to compare `s1[i]` with `s2[i]` like so,

```
int length = s1.length;
for(i=0;i<length;i++)
{
    if(s1[i].equals(s2[i]))
        c++;    
}
if(c==7)
    System.out.println("right way");    
else
    System.out.println("wrong way");
```

This way, you're now comparing each letter in `s1` with each letter in `s2`, assuming you're only entering letters as input to `s2`.

Comment: first  I did (s1[i]==s2[i]) but the c value was coming 0,So I tried to use equals but still c value is coming 0 only.

Comment: @anshu when entering the string input, are you adding capital letters one at a time?

Answer (score 1):

Quick tips:

1. First, add a `.lower()` method to the `.equals()` method to avoid problems resulting from capital letters.
2. You are comparing the entire `s1` array with an `s2[i]` value, you can change the `s1` to `s1[i]`.

New here so please ignore the crappy formatting.

Answer (score 0):

`s1` is a reference to an array, while `s2[i]` is reference to a String, which is why `s1.equals(s2[i])` is evaluating to `false`, which is why `c++` never runs.